# OrderBy function sorting algorithm type

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I'm studying C# LINQ and I want to know what is the type of sorting algorithm used

Comment: If you are studying LINQ, then you need to research the term "LINQ Provider". That will answer your question.

Comment: The only thing specified is that it is a stable sort.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I'm not sure it will - not when it comes to LINQ to Objects, for example. (I don't *think* the sort algorithm is documented... I believe it's quicksort, but I haven't seen that documented.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson And that is for `Enumerable.OrderBy`, no guarantee is given for `Queryable.OrderBy`

Comment: @JonSkeet No, it must be stable, so not quicksort

Comment: I don't believe this warrants an answer, but the underlying implementation will provide the algorithm of choice.  However, it is primarily classified as a *Stable Quicksort*.

Comment: @xanatos: It can be quicksort with additional stability...

Comment: @Jon: IMHO it will tell him that the algorithm depends on the LINQ provider, so that he should not depend on the algorithm.

Comment: If you lookup `System.Linq.EnumerableSorter` it reveals that it is indeed a quick sort.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: That's not an answer to the question of what algorithm *is* used though - it would be worth including the "don't depend on it" part in an answer, of course.

Comment: "I'm studying" implies that you read the documentation and looked at the source, but unfortunately you chose not to provide any information about your careful research in the post. Please in the future make it clear what information you've already found.

Answer (score 7):

It uses quick sort as it can be seen in the [source code for the  EnumerableSorter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,cb26c46274356e0d) class, that is used inside the `OrderedEnumerable` class ,that wraps the source `IEnumerable` inside the `OrderBy` method:

```
   void QuickSort(int[] map, int left, int right) {
        do {
            int i = left;
            int j = right;
            int x = map[i + ((j - i) >> 1)];
            do {
                while (i < map.Length && CompareKeys(x, map[i]) > 0) i++;
                while (j >= 0 && CompareKeys(x, map[j]) < 0) j--;
                if (i > j) break;
                if (i < j) {
                    int temp = map[i];
                    map[i] = map[j];
                    map[j] = temp;
                }
                i++;
                j--;
            } while (i <= j);
            if (j - left <= right - i) {
                if (left < j) QuickSort(map, left, j);
                left = i;
            }
            else {
                if (i < right) QuickSort(map, i, right);
                right = j;
            }
        } while (left < right);
    }
}
```

The algorithm used in the `OrderedEnumerable` to sort is:

1. Select the keys
2. Order the map of indexes using Hoare's sort.
3. Select from the original sequence (turned into Buffer - some IList) items according to the given map of indexes

   ```
      //  EnumerableSorter<TElement> does #1 and #2
      internal int[] Sort(TElement[] elements, int count) {
           ComputeKeys(elements, count);
           int[] map = new int[count];
           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) map[i] = i;
           QuickSort(map, 0, count - 1);
           return map;
       }

    // OrderedEnumerable<TElement>.GetEnumerator() does #3
    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator() {
           Buffer<TElement> buffer = new Buffer<TElement>(source);
           if (buffer.count > 0) {
               EnumerableSorter<TElement> sorter = GetEnumerableSorter(null);
               int[] map = sorter.Sort(buffer.items, buffer.count);
               sorter = null;
               for (int i = 0; i < buffer.count; i++) yield return buffer.items[map[i]];
           }
       }
   ```

**P.S.:** As it is pointed by @JonSkeet `QuickSort` is just the *current* implementation. No one knows whether it will change in some future version or not. Perhaps some optimization will be added for small or specific collections or the algorithm itself will be changed.

Comment: It's probably worth adding that this is the current implementation, but isn't guaranteed. It would be a bad idea to *rely* on any particular algorithm, although it's documented to be stable.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer, I found this answer very helpful for real .. The link you provided is awesome, does it reveal all .NET code ?

Comment: @IbrahimAmer Yes, [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) is an enormously useful thing. As far as I know it contains code for all standard .NET components. You may also be interested in older C++ based [Shared Source Common Language Infrastructure 2.0 Release](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917).

Answer (score 0):

For Object types I believe its quicksort. But I would assume that it probably uses a variety of different sort algorithms depending on the situation and implementation.